# Aifrlow strange UI for tasks

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Why for most tasks I have switch (turn off / turn on) and status for recent task, but for a few I have blue button instead of switch and empty status even if tasks are run.

Default ui:
[image: Default ui]

Additional ui:
[image: Additional ui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is UI bug that's fixed in Airflow 1.9.0+. I *think* it was fixed as part of the pagination refactor in [AIRFLOW-1519](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1519), but I'm not quite sure.